# Route pattern in middleware Slim v3

Tags: php, routes, slim, middleware

How can I get route pattern inside middleware:

routes.php:

```
$app->get('/myroute/{id}', function($req, $res, $args) {
//DO STUFF HERE
})->add(new MyMiddle());
```

middle.php:

```
class MyMiddle {
    public function __invoke($req, $res, $next) {
         //DO STUFF
    }
}
```

In routes.php I can get `{id}` with `$args['id']`, but how can I get it inside MyMiddle.php?

Thank you,
Cristian Molina

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Enable the `determineRouteBeforeAppMiddleware` setting:

   ```
   $config = ['settings' => [
       'determineRouteBeforeAppMiddleware' => true,
       'displayErrorDetails' => true,
   ]];
   $app = new \Slim\App($config);
   ```
2. You can now access the Route object from the Request, using `getAttribute()` and, from the route, get at the arguments:

   ```
   $app->add(function ($request, $response, $next) {
       $id = $request->getAttribute('route')->getArgument('id');
       return $next($request, $response);
   });
   ```

Comment: Thank you, works perfect :D. I'd appreciate so much if this little things were in the documentation. (If they are, please, said to me, maybe I'm blind (probably xD) and don't see them).

Comment: We'd love more contributions to the documentation website :)

Comment: Oh, just say to me how can I improve your docs. I use Slim a lot and I love it, so I'm glad to participate. And if you want, maybe I can start a spanish translation. I'm from Spain xD. This is my email legomolina@gmail.com. So please send me one if you want to I start a translation.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to included a Slim v2 example as that is what I was looking for when I came across this post.  You can use `$this->app->router()->getCurrentRoute()->getPattern()` from the `slim.before.dispatch` callback hook to accomplish the same thing.